# Oracle query to fetch missing value in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Please help me to provide a solution to fetch the missing value

Table: Student

```
 Stud_ID    Stud_Name   Subject
 S001        Peter      Mathematics
 S001        Garry      Physics
 S001        Mike       English

 S002        JOhn       Physics
 S002        Nike       English

 S003        Jim        Mathematics

 S004        Kerry      English
 s004        Michel     Mathematics
```

I need to write an oracle query to fetch the student name, which he don't have the subject "Physics"

I tried a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE SUBJECT NOT IN('Physics')
```

But it doesn't fetch the records as I expected. Appreciate if any one could provide a solution.

Comment: What is the meaning of Stud_ID? Why can each student have many firstnames?

Comment: But why is your title shouting at us?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try below one

```
SELECT stud_Name
FROM STUDENT
WHERE stud_id NOT IN (SELECT stud_id FROM STUDENT WHERE subject='PHYSICS');
```

Comment: Above query will still fetch stud_id S001 and S002, i dont want this, because S001 AND S002 having the physics record

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stud_id FROM student WHERE subject  IN ('Physics')
```

will give you the student which have Physics. You don't want them. So:

```
select * 
from students
where stud_id not in (SELECT stud_id FROM student WHERE subject  IN ('Physics'))
```

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a correlated sub-query (in a single table scan):

```
SELECT stud_id
FROM   student
GROUP BY stud_id
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN subject = 'Physics' THEN 1 END ) = 0;
```

If you want to get the list of names then you can do:

```
SELECT stud_id,
       LISTAGG( stud_name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY stud_name ) AS stud_names
FROM   student
GROUP BY stud_id
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN subject = 'Physics' THEN 1 END ) = 0;
```